# AJAX tarda mucho en regresar información

Tags: ajax, laravel-8

Estoy realizando una aplicación  usando AJAX, recibo los datos sin ningún problema aun que tarda un minuto aproximadamente, por lo que se me hace un poco raro, cuando hago una búsqueda de un dato con ayuda de DataTable tarda mucho en recibir una respuesta
Alguien que pueda ayudarme en reducir el tiempo de respuesta o en saber cual es el error
**Este seria mi controlador**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\medico;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use DataTables;
class ControllerMedico extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $medico = DB::select('CALL ListadoMedico ()');
            return DataTables::of($medico)
            ->addColumn('action', function($medico){
                $acciones = '<a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Editar</a>';
                $acciones = '<a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"> Editar</a>';
                return $acciones;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
        
        }
        return view('medico.index');
    }
}
```

**Este seria mi codio ajax, lei que usando  serverSide el problema se solucionaría pero aun así colocandolo sigo teniendo el mismo problema**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var tablaMedico =  $("#medico").DataTable( {
        processing:true,     
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        ordering: false,
        
        ajax:{
            url: "{{ route('/') }}",
            },
            
                columns:[
                    {data:'id_medico'},
                    {data: 'nombre'},
                    {data: 'ap'},
                    {data: 'am'},
                    {data: 'email'},
                    {data: 'action', orderable: false}
                    
                    
                    
                ],
               
                "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página",
                "zeroRecords": "Registro no encontrado - Revisar con el administrador",
                "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de_MAX_ total de registros)",
                "search": 'Buscar:',
                "paginate":{
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                }
            },
                
        
            
        } );
} );
```

**No se si mi consulta este mal uso SQLyog**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
 PROCEDURE ListMedi()
BEGIN
    SELECT id_medico,nombre,ap,am,email
    FROM medico;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar más información acerca de tu aplicación? ¿Qué marco de trabajo de PHP estás usando? ¿Cuántos registros tiene la tabla `medico`? ¿Por qué haces uso de un procedimiento almacenado para una tarea tan simple como listar el contenido de una tabla? ¿Estás en un entorno de desarrollo local o usando un servidor externo? ¿En qué sistema operativo?

Comment: Estoy utilizando el framework laravel 8.0 , hice la prueba con 10,000 registros pero por lo que he visto mucho hacen la prueba con mas datos y no tienen ningún problema, habia realizado una consulta normal pero tenia el mismo resultado , estoy en un servidor local y con windows 7